# The mode of multivariate Gamma distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution, multivariate-distribution, mode

Let X, Y, Z be i.i.d. distributed Gamma random variables. What could the mode of the vector $(X, X+Y, X+Y+Z)$ be?

Does the mode of a random vector equal the combination of the marginal modes?

Comment: The last question is interesting.  You can construct counterexamples using bivariate Bernoulli variables (that is, $2\times 2$ contingency tables): try it!

Comment: The general answer to the second question is no\*. It's worth trying various simulations and some algebra. $\quad$ *I suspect (but haven't checked) that its not the case for your specific problem.

Comment: For multivariate mode see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210107/whats-the-definition-of-multivariate-mode   and    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33625/computationally-efficient-estimation-of-multivariate-mode

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91937 is also relevant (it concerns comparing marginal modes to the joint mode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's address the questions in reverse order.

First, **there isn't any general relationship between the marginal modes and the joint mode for arbitrary multivariate random variables.**  Counterexamples and explanations are given in the answers at [How are the numbers of modes of marginal and joint distributions related?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91937).

Despite that, **in the special circumstances of the first question (*iid* continuous variables), there is a nice, simple result.** To obtain it, let $f$ be the common density function.  The independence assumption means the joint density is their product,

$$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = f(x)\,f(y)\,f(z).$$

In the change of variables $(X,U,V) = (X,X+Y,X+Y+Z),$ the probability element transforms as

$$\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}(x+y)\,\mathrm{d}(x+y+z) = \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z;$$

that is, *it is unchanged.*  (The statistical argot is "the Jacobian equals $1$ everywhere."  The actual calculation is performed with the wedge product as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154298/919.)  This is the key insight, because it means the maximum value of the joint distribution is obtained by maximizing

$$f_{X,U,V}(x,u,v) = f(x)\,f(u-x)\,f(v-u).$$

All such maxima *obviously* occur at points $(x,u,v)$ where $x,$ $u-x,$ and $v-u$ are modes of $f.$  Thus

> The modes of the joint distribution of $(X,X+Y,X+Y+Z)$ are the points $(x^{*},x^{*}+y^{*},x^{*}+y^{*}+z^{*})$ where $x^{*},$ $y^{*},$ and $z^{*}$ are univariate modes of the common marginal distribution of $X,$ $Y,$ and $Z.$

**When $f$ has a unique mode $x^{*},$ this implies $f_{X,U,V}$ has a unique mode at $(x^{*}, 2x^{*}, 3x^{*}).$**  This is the situation of the question, because a $\Gamma(k,\theta)$ distribution ($\theta$ is a scale parameter) has a unique mode at $x^{*}=(k-1)\theta$ when $k\ge 1$ (and otherwise its mode is $x^{*}=0$).

---

It is apparent that results of this type are available for any number of *iid* continuous variables and any invertible linear transformation (because again the Jacobian is constant and so does not affect the joint mode).