# What's the definition of multivariate mode?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mode, multivariate-distribution

In the case of grouped data where a frequency curve have been constructed to fit the data, the mode will be the value (or values) of $x$ corresponding to the maximum point (or points) on the curve. From a frequency distribution or histogram, the mode can be obtained from the formula:

$$Mode = L_{1} + c \frac{f_{2}}{f_{1}+f_{2}}$$

where $L_{1}$ = Lower class boundary of modal class (i.e., the class containing the mode).
$c$ = Size of modal class interval.
$f_{1}$ = Frequency of the class previous to the modal class.
$f_{2}$ = Frequency of the class just after the modal class.

Is there any general definition for MODE for bivariate or multivariate data? Should we use, for example, rectangle in bivariate case (interval is for univariate)?

Comment: This free first page http://www.jstor.org/stable/2958856?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents of "Estimation of a Multivariate Mode " by Sager, 1978 The Annals of Statistics, will give you an idea of a variety of possible ways of defining multivariate mode, such as based on boxes or spheres (which comes down to which distance metric is used to define a neighborhood), or other convex sets. There is a choice. The choice has computational implications. You can find a lot more (more recent) links by googling on multivariate mode.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

This free first page https://www.jstor.org/stable/2958856?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents of "Estimation of a Multivariate Mode " by Sager, 1978 The Annals of Statistics, will give you an idea of a variety of possible ways of defining multivariate mode, such as based on boxes or spheres (which comes down to which distance metric is used to define a neighborhood), or other convex sets. There is a choice. The choice has computational implications. You can find a lot more (more recent) links by googling on multivariate mode. – Mark L. Stone

A free version of the same paper can be found at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176344253    HINT:  All papers from *annals of statistics* can be found free at projecteuclid.org